# Div not the right size possibly due to padding

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I've got two divs that should appear the same but don't. If I follow the syntax of the first way, the div has the right width (60px) but if I do it the second way it's only 44px. I need to use the second way. Why are there differences in sizes?

EDIT: I also noticed that there seems to be no spacing before and after the letters if I use the second way. Maybe something to do with padding..

**First way**

```
<div id="item_2", onclick="location.href='http://www.facebook.com';" style="cursor:pointer;"> About </div>
```

**Second way**

```
<%= link_to "http://www.facebook.com", id:"item_2" do %> About <% end %>
```

**CSS**

```
#item_2 {
    width: 60px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in First Way: you are Using Div Tag, that is Block level element.

in Second Way: you are Using a (Anchor) Tag, that is Inline element.

Note:Inline Element Width Automatically Adjust with its Content, not Through CSS
if you want to Implement CSS Width then Make it Block Level or Set Float Level

For First Way CSS to Make DIV Tag Inline

```
#item_2 {
    display:inline;
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

================================

## OR

For Second Way CSS to Make Anchor Tag Block

```
   #item_2 {
        display:block;
        width:60px;
        padding-top: 11px;
        padding-bottom: 11px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
You Should use Seprately CSS for Anchor Tag

Way 1: Globaly for Anchor Tag

```
   a {
        display:block;
        width:60px;
        padding-top: 11px;
        padding-bottom: 11px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Way 2

```
   a#item_2 {
        display:block;
        width:60px;
        padding-top: 11px;
        padding-bottom: 11px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Way 3
Give Anchor Tag Seprate id or Class
for Example

```
<a class='item_n' >Link</a>
```

CSS

```
.item_n {

            display:block;
            width:60px;
            padding-top: 11px;
            padding-bottom: 11px;
            text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @InventorX. Unfortunately it still doesn't work for me if I try the second way to make the anchor tag block. Should I set CSS for the a tag instead of #item_2 btw?

Answer (score -2):

As the second example is an `<a>` instead of a `<div>` you should set it as "`display: block;`"

Check this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hige/7puyk/

Comment: Could you provide an actual example to improve this answer?